# Get several items using registry.js (uiRegistry)

Tags: javascript, uicomponent, magento2.1.0, ui-form

I have several elements inside Ui form with default param (each):

```
'dependsOn' => 'assign_type'
```

and I want to get all that items inside the another js component of my form.

I try to use the **`uiRegistry`** (*vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/registry/registry.js*) like this:

```
uiRegistry.get('dependsOn = assign_type');
```

but in this case the registry (`$p` variable is `uiRegistry` object) returns only the first element:

[image: element]

[image: elements index]

This example from the documentation does not help:

```
* @example Requesting multiple elements.
*      registry.set('second', {index: 'test2'});
*      registry.get(['first', 'second'], function (first, second) {});
```

Result, got one item (first item) three times:

[image: result of Requesting multiple elements example]

**Question is**: How to receive several similar elements using the registry? Perhaps somebody knows other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I found an answer. The `filter` method return all items by search criteria in the array:

```
    /**
     * Retrieves a collection of elements that match
     * provided search criteria.
     *
     * @param {(Object|String|Function)} query - Search query.
     *      See 'get' method for the syntax examples.
     * @returns {Array} Found elements.
     */
    filter: function (query) {
        return find(getItems(this), query, true);
    },
```

so, if I use `$p.filter('dependsOn = assign_type')` (where the `$p` is `uiRegistry` object) I receive all items:

[image: result]